# Grails keep deleting my tables

Tags: database, grails

I have my table structure like:

CREATE  TABLE `test_two_tabel`.`T1` (  `T1_ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,  `A1` INT NULL ,  `B1` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,  `C1` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,  `D1` DATETIME NULL ,  PRIMARY KEY (`T1_ID`) );

In Grails:

```
package twotables

class T1 {

    Integer a
    String b
    String c
    Date d

    static mapping = {
        table "T1"
        version false
        id column:"T1_ID"
        a1 column:"a1"
        b1 column:"b1"
        c1 column:"c1"
        d1 column:"d1"
    }

    static constraints = {
        id()
        a1()
        b1()
        c1()
        d1()
    }
}
```

Every time I execute my program... Grails deletes my tables in the DB, does anyone know what's happening?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to change value of dbCreate from 'create-drop' to 'update' at `grails-app/conf/DataSource.groovy`

You current value probably is:

```
development {
    dataSource {
        dbCreate = "create-drop" // one of 'create', 'create-drop','update'
        url = "***"
    }
}
```

this means that Grails will **recreate all tables on every restart**. If you'll set this as `update` it will try to update table structure, according to your data model classes.

You can read more about Grails DB configuration at http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/3.%20Configuration.html#3.3%20The%20DataSource

Answer (score -1):

it could be a few things. As @splix mentioned, it could be the 'create-drop' settings.

Also, if you never changed your datasource, Grails uses an in-memory database, so it only lasts as long as the program runs.  You can tell hsqldb to persist to file instead of be in memory.  You can also change it to point to something like mysql.  Look [here](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/3.%20Configuration.html#3.3%20The%20DataSource).

Comment: And what if none of these conditions are true. I'm using the Grails migration plugin, a designed NON-memory database, and Grails will erratically drop all the tables, but leave the migration tables unchanged, making it impossible to easily re-create all the tables.